# How fix input and state in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

Have

```
const [grade, setGrade] = useState({grade: null,})

const changeHandler = (event) => {if (event.value) {setGrade({ ...grade, [event.name]: event.value })} else {setGrade({ ...grade, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })}}
```

and input

```
<input
                  type="text"
                  name="grade"
                  className="homework-block-main-input"
                  onClick={changeHandler}
                  />
```

when i print value in input i have

print "1"
have ""
print "12"
have "1"
print "123"
have "12"

How to fix that?

when i print value in input i have

print "1"
have ""
print "12"
have "1"
print "123"
have "12"

How to fix that?

Comment: Remove onClick and use onChange.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to point out is that `if (event.value) {}` doesn't make sense because event.value doesn't exists in event so it's always undefined, second thing, you should use onChange instead of onClick, the onClick event is generally used in buttons, third thing, you should do a console.log inside a useEffect to track the state correctly, here how you code should looks like:

```
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState({ grade: '' });

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setGrade({ grade: event.target.value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(grade)
  }, [grade]);  

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="grade"
      className="homework-block-main-input"
      onChange={changeHandler}
    ></input>
  );
};
```